# Python commands not found and alias for python3 bin

Tags: python, path, binary

I am new to python and I have found myself struggling with the cohabitation of python2.x and python3.x versions on my mac.

Eventually I have understood that python2 is located at the usual root for binaries, ie `/usr/local/bin` while python3 is in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` with aliases in `/usr/local/bin` (for instance python3 for using Python 3.6, pip3, etc.)

Now I wanted to follow some tutorials for using Flask:

```
sudo pip3 install flask
```

did work but didn't create an alias such as flask3 in `/usr/local/bin`. I have been facing the same issue with virtualenv.

My question now is: is it better to create manually aliases (flask3 or virtualenv3 for instance) or to add to the `$PATH` the python 3. binaries. The second option seems easier but I am worrying about potential conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I would add it to `$PATH` in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. If you do this, you always know that you made changes in the configuration file for your bash shell.

Linking on the other hand is something you will forget about over time. If an error occurs later on, you will have to search for that link. Updates of OS X may even break the link.

The bottom line is that adding it to `$PATH` is cleaner. Errors and conflicts can appear using either method.

Comment: what if some scripts in both folders share the same name ?

Comment: If that's the case, the first one in ``$PATH`` is used. So you have to be cautious if you are appending ``$PATH`` to the path to the python executable or the other way around.